LIKE operation in Panache
This is my first time working with PANACHE.
I am trying to call a simple query but I get returned a empty list.
This is the code
 val paramsMap = Parameters()
 paramsMap.and("guuid", "092ed247-887e-4ffe-8b9e-876c307c038")
  
 val panacheQuery = find(":guuid IS NULL OR GUUID = :guuid OR GUUID LIKE '%' || :guuid || '%'", paramsMap)

val en = panacheQuery.list<MldEntity>()
println(en)

These two work:

Changing the guuid to null : returns all data

Changing the guuid to 123 : returns the row with guuid 123


Seems like when it sees ¨like¨ it just skips it, so I am wondering if like is allowed in panache?
It works when i run in sql console

change the value of GUUID to NULL it works as it should?

Hi Thank you for your comment, Yes when guuid is null i get the expected result, which is the whole table, I also get the expected result when i change guuid to a corresponding value in the table.
